# Maven and Clearcase integration

Tags: maven-2, maven

I want to integrate Maven with Clearcase, I am using 7.1 version in UCM mode with dynamic view.

I am new to maven and need to integrate for an existing project. Please let me know what steps I need to follow to integrate Maven and clearcase.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Maven documentation: http://maven.apache.org/scm/clearcase.html